# VBA Loop not going to next Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code where I want to skip "Sheet1".  However, the Loop skips "Sheet1", and then Ends the Sub.  It does not move to the `Next ws`.

There are 7 Worksheets..

[image]

How do I fix this please?

```
Sub BrandRank_()

    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim LstObj As ListObjects

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then

'Insert Table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight), xlYes).Name = TableName

'Apply a filter to "C3" (Largest to Smallest)
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("C3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    .ListObjects(TableName).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False

        End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out all the table/filter manipulation inside the loop? For one thing, you're not assigning a value to `TableName`. Is there any additional code not shown here?

Comment: That loop looks fine - there's nothing which should cause it to exit early.

Comment: `.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)` looks like it should be enclosed in an outer `Range` call.

Comment: @JoshEller, the loop doesn't even get to the `'Insert Table` step.  It skips straight to `End if, End With, Next ws, End Sub`

Comment: Well, how many worksheets are in `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: @BigBen would this be better? Data goes from `A3:L`, and I'm trying to make sure I catch the last row.. `.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A3:L" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), , xlYes).Name = "TableName"`

Comment: I would break the calculation of the last row into its own line: `lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @JoshEller - 7 Worksheets.  `Sheet1 thru Sheet7`

Comment: @BigBen - Like this" `Dim LastRow As Long` `LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` `.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A3:L" & LastRow), , xlYes).Name = "TableName"`  The code still goes to `If .Index<>1 Then` and Skips to `End If - End With - Next ws - End Sub`

Comment: Are you sure you have this code in the right workbook? What does `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` return?

Comment: I'm so confused.  It says 1.. Is it trying to run in the VBAProject (Personal.Xlsb) workbook (which is where the Macro is stored)?  How do I get it to run in the only Worksheet I have open?  I can't set it inside a specific worksheet, because it's a data pull worksheet that will change the name every time I run it.

Comment: Well yes, if it's stored in your personal workbook, that's what `ThisWorkbook` will return. Do you mean to be using `ActiveWorkbook` instead?

Comment: @JoshEller, I've been trying to avoid the whole `ActiveWorkbook`.  However if it's stored in my personal workbook, do I need to change the `For Each ws` to `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` to get it to run on a different workbook?

Comment: ^ Yes.... or get the workbook reference some other way (i.e. by name).

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA probably loops through the sheets of your *Personal.xlsb*.

If you are running macros from the external file, then, please, use **thisWorkbook** property to refer to the workbook that contains your macro code. **ThisWorkbook**, for example, is the only way to refer to an add-in workbook from inside the add-in itself.

The **ActiveWorkbook** property doesn't return the add-in workbook; it returns the workbook that's calling the code. It would be even better to refer to a particular workbook directly by name (see below)

I would also suggest considering referring to a sheet by its name, otherwise your code may break unexpectedly if you (or someone else) changes the order of sheets, adds hidden sheets etc.

```
For Each wsSheet In Workbooks("NameOfYourBook").Worksheets

If wsSheet.Name <> "TOC" Then
'Put your code here 
End If
Next wsSheet
```

You may also use the **.CodeName** property.
[See the details.](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Index_to_Access_theWorksheet)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer.  I was originally using **ThisWorkbook**, and it was running the code on the _Personal.xlsb_.   When I change the reference to **ActiveWorkbook**, it now pulls to the other Workbook I need the code to run on.

Comment: The only issue with referencing the Workbook directly by Name is the Name of the workbook is different every time I run/download the data.  i.e.  MyReport (58).xlsm, MyReport(59).xlsm, etc..

Comment: If you have a new workbook each time maybe it will be a better idea to open a workbook and then use the particular reference to it.